# How to retrieve words and their x_start and x_end coordinates within the table in pdf image in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, ocr, tesseract

Is it possible to read table headers like the example code below? To get headers with the data below? column by column

For example, as a result, I want to see the response like this:

```
{
   "ITEM NO.": { x_start: 100, x_end: 220 },
   "DESCRIPTION OF WORK": { x_start: 300, x_end: 420 },
   "ORIGINAL": { x_start: 450, x_end: 550 },
   "CHANGE ORDERS": { x_start: 600, x_end: 720 },
   "CURRENT": { x_start: 750, x_end: 850 },
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: tessaract gives you a bounding box. Maybe you can include some information in what you're doing. If you're using the python library, and what you're getting stuck at.

Comment: I'm using py-tesseract and couldn't read these headers correctly. I want to get headers like in the example above

Comment: In Ruby, I use the rtesseract gem but these words above are located randomly and I wonder is there are some ways to find a solution to get response as above

Comment: You have the image of the headers? Then run it through tesseract and it will give you bounding boxes of all the text.